# Как получить ссылку на корень сайта?

Tags: opencart

Есть ли функция в опенкарт, чтобы получить название сайта?
т.е. допустим при переносе на другой хостинг, чтобы все ссылки небыли привязаны к конкретному хосту

Comment: я так понимаю что вы про шаблоны? почему не делать абсолютные пути? и есть глобальные переменные в опенкарте, HTTP_SERVER и HTTPS_SERVER, которые содержат адреса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При переносе проекта на opencart на другой хост, вам необходимо отредактировать два файла:

```
САЙТ\admin\config.php
```

и

```
САЙТ\config.php
```

В этих файлах лежат когстанты путей на весь проект. В папке `admin` для админки, в корне для фронтенда и системы.

**root/config.php:**

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://сайт.домен/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://сайт.домен/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/root_path/www/catalog/');
// root_path - можете посмотреть на хосте или через __DIR__
define('DIR_SYSTEM',  ...);
...

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'новый_хост');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'новый_юзер');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'новый_пасс');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'новый_база);
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'префикс');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: благодарю, это я знаю. а есть ли для этих целей именно функция opencart? вопрос в этом

Comment: Не специализируюсь на OC. Не понимаю, а чего так не хотите использовать?

Comment: просто иногда приходится работать с опенкарт, делать правки, поэтому хотелось-бы узнать